# Is there an example of solver calculations to show how they work under the hood?

Tags: gto

I am trying to understand how solvers work, but most GTO books just give examples of easy and straight forward toy games and then they jump to outputs from solvers and I feel there is some gap between those easy games and solvers results.

Is there some public example in a book, video tutorial or anything of how the solvers work in sort of "step by step" manner to fully understand how the results are obtained?

Comment: Heya only saw your question today, I think you may struggle to find step by step exactly as folks are charging for their solver algorithms, however you can find fairly good posts about it from a higher level. I found a nice article on it here - https://www.888poker.com/magazine/poker-world/poker-solvers-made-easy#:~:text=A%20poker%20solver%20is%20a,poker%20solver%20are%20relatively%20minimal.

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer as I feel I don't answer the actual question of the 'under the hood' and the 'step by step' you're looking for. I think you may struggle to find that. I do also know of this opensource one, which if you're so inclined you could read the code and probably work out how it is reaching it's conclusions. https://github.com/bupticybee/TexasSolver